# How to search for a key in HGETALL response in redis?

Tags: redis

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall "box_vehicle_mapping"
1) "A9AC"
2) "{\"box_version\": \"v8_3zo\", \"box_sub_version\": \"8\", \"box_number\": \"A9AC\", \"box_usage_type\": \"vehicle\", \"version\": 8, \"current_state\": 2, \"registration_number\": [\"KA-03-AE-0017\"]}"
3) "A99V"
4) "{\"registration_number\": \"KA-05-AH-8889\", \"box_version\": \"v8_3zo\"}"
5) "A9A3"
6) "{\"box_version\": \"v8_3zo\", \"box_sub_version\": 17, \"box_number\": \"A9A3\", \"box_usage_type\": \"vehicle\", \"version\": 8, \"current_state\": 2, \"registration_number\": [\"KA-03-AE-0016\"]}"
7) "A9AD"
8) "{\"box_version\": \"v8_3zo\", \"box_sub_version\": \"12\", \"box_number\": \"A9AD\", \"box_usage_type\": \"vehicle\", \"version\": 8, \"current_state\": 2, \"registration_number\": [\"KA-03-AE-0021\"]}"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

How can i do a search over it, say I want to know if "A99V" key is present in the result of hgetall key?

Comment: Do you mean wildcard search?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`HEXISTS`](https://redis.io/commands/hexists/) if all you care about is one key existing, or [`HGET`](https://redis.io/commands/hget/) to get one value.

```
HGET box_vehicle_mapping A99V
```